# mpstat not showing all CPUs on CentOS 5.5 (64 bit)

Tags: centos, multi-core

I have two Quad Core XEON processors. When I run "mpstat" then it just shows combine figure of all CPUs like this:

```
12:16:44 AM  CPU   %user   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal   %idle    intr/s
12:16:44 AM  all   19.93    0.01    9.25    0.08    0.00    0.02    0.00   70.70    430.73
```

How can I see individual CPU load?

Thanks

Comment: Ok I got it. I should run "mpstat -P ALL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-P cpu | ALL option indicate the processor number for which statistics are to be reported:

```
  mpstat -P ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-A` flag will give you that, and a lot more.

```
10:21:51 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
10:21:51 PM  all    1.34    0.32    0.59    0.66    0.02    0.01    0.00    0.00   97.06
10:21:51 PM    0    1.48    0.37    0.62    1.32    0.06    0.04    0.00    0.00   96.11
10:21:51 PM    1    1.20    0.21    0.72    0.13    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.73
10:21:51 PM    2    1.48    0.43    0.46    0.88    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.72
10:21:51 PM    3    1.21    0.25    0.56    0.29    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.67
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `top`. Type `1` to show individual CPU statistics.